# What happens when I run `docker start image_name`?

Tags: docker

I understand that `docker start` starts a container and `docker run` creates and starts a container given an image. But naively at first I just ran the command `docker start image_name` and it just outputs image_name to the console and no container is created and started.

Does `docker start image_name` do anything besides echo the name to the console? The [doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/) is not very illustrative. If so, what a bad way to fail, better would have been to tell me, that that is not a container but an image and I should first create a container, but maybe I'm missing some useful action which `docker start image_name` does?

Comment: My version (20.10.18) outputs the following: `Error response from daemon: No such container: <image_name>
Error: failed to start containers: <image_name>` (tested it with an already existing image on my host)

Comment: I see, I have 20.10.12, so they also thought the behavior I get is not nice and changed it to a sensible error message, good to see. Now I wonder if in my version it does anything besides echo

Answer (score 1):

> What happens when I run `docker start image_name`?

```
$ docker start --help

Usage:  docker start [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Start one or more stopped containers
```

> it just outputs image_name to the console and no container is created and started

```
a, --attach               Attach STDOUT/STDERR and forward signals
```

The default is not to attach.

> Does docker start image_name do anything besides echo the name to the console?

Yes it `Start(-s) one or more stopped containers`.

> I'm missing some useful action which docker docker start image_name does?

It restarts the stopped container.

```
$ docker run --name work alpine sh -c 'echo important_work ; sleep 10 ; echo success'
important_work
success
$ docker start -a work
important_work
success
```

Most probably your container that you tested does nothing or expects interactive session to work, and without input it just exits.

Comment: The OP asks what happens when you try to `start` an `image` and not a `container` ;-)

Comment: And I suspect OP mixed the terms image with container, and your comment states what happens on image.

Comment: I did not confuse the terms image and container. And this does not answer my question. Please read my question carefully

Comment: Then `docker start image_name` will fail with no such container.