# How to find the udev rule which causes the loading of the kernel module 88XXau.ko?

Tags: linux, wifi, linux-device-driver, udev

In my Linux distribution I use an Edimax **EW-7811UTC** Wi-Fi USB Adapter.

#### Installation of the driver rtl8812au

I have installed the driver `rtl8812au` from source by following steps:

- building of the kernel module `88XXau.ko` (command `make`) from source
- installing it in the directory: `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/` (command `make install`)

This driver support many Wi-Fi adapter, but I need to **write a script** or something else to load the module `88XXau.ko` only if the Wi-Fi adapter is exactly the Edimax EW-7811UTC.

#### The module 88XXau.ko is automatically loaded

I want to show 2 scenarios:

- by the command `lsmod`, I have checked that at boot time if the Wifi-USB adapter **is not** plugged in, the module `88XXau.ko` is not loaded.
- when I plug in the WiFi-USB adapter the kernel and `udev` automatically load the module (I have check this by the command `lsmod | grep 88XXau`), but I can not find the specific `udev rule` which executes this loading.

I haven't written any `udev rule`, so in the Linux distribution must be present a default `udev rule` responsible of this automatic loading of the kernel module `88XXau.ko`.

#### The problem: find the udev rule

To reach my goal that is to load the module only if the WiFi adapter is the Edimax EW-7811UTC, I need to disable the automatism so I'm here to ask if someone could show me a procedure to find the default `udev rule` for this driver?

Thanks

Comment: By the answer of @KamilCuk (see below) I have found the udev rule; so his answer - **very very synthetic** - for me is enough. But I have to disable the rule because with it, udev mounts the module 88XXau.ko every time it is plugged in a WiFi adapter that it can manage. Requirements for my projects limit the mount for only Edimax EW-7811UTC. If I remove the rule ENV{MODALIAS}=="?*", RUN{builtin}+="kmod load '$env{MODALIAS}'" I will must to find an other way to load the module.

Comment: So write a rule to load it only if you plug in your adapter... ?

Comment: @KamilCuk thank you. Obvious and clear! When I will restart to work on this task I will open a new question about this topic but I don't know if stackoverflow is suite for this type of question. As you can see this question have been closed immediatly after I wrote it.

Comment: If this is usb, usually I find what are the revision:something numbers from lsusb , and create /etc/udev.d/rules file with rule with those revision:something numbers. It's very rarely that someone plugs in two exact same usb devices. Something like..... (pulls notes) `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04d8", ATTR{idProduct}=="000b", RUN{builtin}+="kmod load '$env{MODALIAS}'"`

Comment: There are so many questions already, https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=udev+rule+for+usb https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=udev+rule+for+usb . `this question have been closed immediatly` Stackoverflow is for _programming_, specifically. See unix.stackexchange .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter09/udev.html

> Device drivers compiled as modules may have aliases built into them.
> Aliases are visible in the output of the modinfo program and are
> usually related to the bus-specific identifiers of devices supported
> by a module. For example, the snd-fm801 driver supports PCI devices
> with vendor ID 0x1319 and device ID 0x0801, and has an alias of
> “pci:v00001319d00000801sv*sd*bc04sc01i*”. For most devices, the bus
> driver exports the alias of the driver that would handle the device
> via sysfs. E.g., the /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:0d.0/modalias file
> might contain the string
> “pci:v00001319d00000801sv00001319sd00001319bc04sc01i00”. The default
> rules provided with udev will cause udevd to call out to
> /sbin/modprobe with the contents of the MODALIAS uevent environment
> variable (which should be the same as the contents of the modalias
> file in sysfs), thus loading all modules whose aliases match this
> string after wildcard expansion.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Modalias

```
$ cd /usr/lib/udev/rules.d
$ grep -r MODALIAS .
80-drivers.rules
5:ENV{MODALIAS}=="?*", RUN{builtin}+="kmod load '$env{MODALIAS}'"
```

Comment: In my yocto distribuition I have the **udev** rules file `80-drivers.rules` and inside it I have found the rule:  `ENV{MODALIAS}=="?*", RUN{builtin}+="kmod load '$env{MODALIAS}'"`. But if I execute the command `kmod load 88XXau`, busybox give me an error message with the information that the sub-commands allowed are: `help, show, static-nodes`. This means that **load** is not a sub-command allowed for the command **kmod** available in my distribution.

Comment: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/src/udev/udev-builtin-kmod.c#L27 Not a command, builtin.

Comment: Because the file `80-drivers.rules` is the default file created by my Yocto platform is strange that it requests the execution of a command with a sintax not allowed by BusyBox.. So the load of the module **88XXau** depens on some other event?

Comment: `kmod` is not a command here. It's a udev builtin. It doesn't execute the command. It executes the source code I linked to. I do not understand.

Comment: Kamil I am not expert on **udev** and I haven't noted that in the rule is defined `RUN{builtin}` and not `RUN`. So do you think that the module loading is executed by this rule: `ENV{MODALIAS}=="?*", RUN{builtin}+="kmod load '$env{MODALIAS}'"`?

Comment: Kamil I've excluded the rule `ENV{MODALIAS}=="?*", RUN{builtin}+="kmod load '$env{MODALIAS}'` from the file `80-drivers.rules` and the module stop loading when the Wifi-USB adapter is plugged in. If I add the rule again, the module is again automatically loaded. Thanks very much.

Comment: (Off-topic, will delete this comment. Would you consider undeleting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73811481)? The OP was a bit rude, but your answer was very good - the question was deleted and mod undeleted, and your answer looks like it would be worth keeping).